# The current time in seconds gives the wrong value

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to get the current time of the user's phone in seconds and I use this code:

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance().time.time / 1000
```

But I noticed that the time returns to me an hour earlier, while I tested the following code, the time returns correctly!

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance().time
```

Where do you think the problem could be?

Comment: Consider not using `Calendar` since it is an old and outdated class that was always cumbersome to work with. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with. For the current time in seconds since the Unix epoch use `Instant.now().getEpochSecond()`.

Comment: Please give a specific example of expected result of hte first code line, observed result and correct result from your second code line. As the question stands we haven’t got a clue and would rather suspect an error on your part.